# Resizing a Svg background image repeat

Tags: html, css, svg

I add a simple decorative svg in my div:

```
.advantages {
    color: #B3B3B3;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 21px;
    background: url(../svg/curvy-bg.svg) center bottom repeat-x, #FBFBFB;
    background-size: 32%;
}
```

The problem is that the svg shows separate white space between the repeat-x...

[Check the problem here](https://jsfiddle.net/q3geyevk/2/)

If you resize the screen in the jsfiddle you can see how the curvy background changes it's white space.

I don´t want the white spaces.

What´s the problem?

Answer (score -2):

Edit background in your code

```
.advantages {
    color: #B3B3B3;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 21px;
    background: #f5f5f5 url(http://imgh.us/curvy-bg2.svg) repeat-x center bottom;
    background-size: 32%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q3geyevk/5/

Comment: If you reduce the screen appears white spaces between the background, this is my problem

Comment: One simple: remove white spaces in svg file

Comment: the svg file not have white spaces

Comment: If it's what I think it is, open up your SVG file and change the root <svg> element so that it includes the following attribute:

<svg ... preserveAspectRatio="none">

Comment: That still doesn't solve the problem. Why are there so many answers claiming it does? preserveAspectRatio="none" does absolutely nothing for SVGs included as CSS backgrounds.